# DownloadManager freezes ui

Tags: android

I'm trying to use DownloadManager to load multiple files (100+), while enqueuing file urls app freeze and while downloading files app is really lag.

```
    DownloadManager downloadManager = ( DownloadManager ) context.getSystemService( Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE );
    DownloadManager.Request request;

    long[] ids = new long[ tiles.size() ];
    int cpt = 0;

    for ( MapUtils.Tile tile : tiles )
    {
        String path = "/tiles/" + provider.getId() + "/" + tile.getZ() + "/" + tile.getX() + "/" + tile.getY() + ".jpg";
        File file = new File( context.getExternalFilesDir( null ) + path );

        Log.d( "MapUtils", "download " + file.getPath() + " --- " + file.exists() );

        if ( file.exists() ) file.delete();

        request = new DownloadManager.Request( Uri.parse( tile.getUrl( provider.getUrl() ) ) );
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes( DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE );
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming( false );
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi( false );
        request.setTitle( tile.getUrl( provider.getUrl() ) );
        request.setNotificationVisibility( DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN );
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir( context, null, path );
        ids[ cpt ] = downloadManager.enqueue( request );
        cptt+

    }
```

for loop freeze app here and it take a while to enqueue all files

```
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
        {
            DownloadManager manager = ( DownloadManager ) getSystemService( Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE );
            String action = intent.getAction();
             Log.d( "BroadcastReceiver", "action " + action );
            if ( DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals( action ) )
            {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0 );
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                 Log.d( "BroadcastReceiver", "downloadId" + downloadId + " - " + manager.getUriForDownloadedFile( downloadId ) );

                Cursor c = manager.query( query );
                if ( c.moveToFirst() )
                {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex( DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS );
                    if ( DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt( columnIndex ) )
                    {
                        Log.d( "BroadcastReceiver", "complete" );
                    }
                }
                c.close();
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver( receiver , new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE ) );
```

After all files are enqueued, i start receiving complete callbacks, app is not totally frozen anymore but very laggy.

I read DownloadManager is executing in background so i don't get it.
Thx for your help!

Comment: *I read DownloadManager is executing in background so i don't get it* ... but your `for` loop is on the main thread ... also `onReceive` of BroadcastReceiver (where you are itereing the cursor of all download every time when manager finish the download)

Comment: Ok so i need to wrap this in an asynctask?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things at play here which are slowing your app down:

- Creating a new `BroadcastReceiver` for each file and registering it. This causes new object creation and Cris process communication with the framework, both are expensive.
- Deleting files in the loop. File I/O of and kind is slow, so this can potentially cause delays.
- Use of `Cursor` in the `onReceive()` method. This is another potentially expensive processing call. The `DownloadManager` is in another process, so the query is going cross process and cursor operations are often slow.

Things to do to help:

- use a single `BroadcastReceiver` to handle the response from `DownloadManager`
- do not query the `DownloadManager` to process completed files. The `id` in the `Intent` tells you which file completed, if you need more status information and to take an action, use some type of deferred processing like a thread.
- if you don't need to re-download a file, don't delete the existing one and force a re-download

Comment: Ok thx for the tips, one more question my donwloads may last even if i switch activity, should i run a simple thread from my activity that start my download or should i use  a intentservice? thx

Comment: Using a thread from an `Activity` won't do what you expect.  Once the `Activity` is no longer on the screen, it is not in a running state and anything it started should be cleaned up.  `IntentService` is also not likely to do what you expect as it processes an `Intent` in a background thread then immediately shuts down once there are no more `Intent`s to process.

Comment: So what do you recommand to use to handle long download in background? thx

Comment: `DownloadManager` is made just for that purpose, so there's nothing wrong with using it.  In fact, that's preferred if you're just pulling files which are eventually to be used.  It all gets back to your use case.  If these are assets which are somehow needed for UI presentation to the user, then you should look into using something like Volley or if they are images look at Universal Image Loader or Picasso to handle pulling down assets in non-main thread context.

Comment: To give your more info, i'm actually loading osm map tiles to cache them so user can display map offline. I'm ok to use `DownloadManager` but my main problem is that my app freeze when i enqueue tiles url from a loop `downloadManager.enqueue( request );`, it looks like it take times to enqueue all those urls. So i guess i'll still have to use a thread or service or something :) to at least enqueue url in `DownloadManager`?

Comment: Double check that it is actually the `enqueue` call that is taking the time.  It shouldn't be.  It's most likely your creation and registration of a new `BroadcastReceiver` each pass through the loop.

Comment: traceview and systrace can be used to profile what is going on and see where the bottlenecks are at.